# What to do with tons of old infernal machines in diablo 3?

Tags: diablo-iii

Now hellfire ring is different http://d3domination.com/diablo-3-guides/hellfire-ring-crafting-reaper-souls/

Yet I still have 15 infernal machines I don't use

My plan was to use a level 70 character to do uber in the equivalent of MP 10 thingy. But there is no such thing as MP 10 thingy.

Will my plan gives me advantages I think I deserve? After all getting a lvl 60 ring for a lvl 70 character shouldn't be tough. Can that be done?

Comment: What advantages are you looking for?  Killing level 60 ubers at level 70, even at Torment 6, gives you, at best, a 50% chance to drop the items to craft the ring.  And it's not nearly as good as the stuff you can find at level 70.

Comment: Maybe I should have one of my friend make a lvl 60 game and then ask friends lvl 70 to join. That way I got much easier ubber.

Comment: @Krazer no, you can't. You can only equip 1 *Hellfire Ring*, whether it's *Legacy* or not

Comment: @Novarg that's not what [Blue says](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/11914021942?page=1#4).

Comment: @Krazer which is not the case with *Hellfire Rings*: http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/9728152873#15

Comment: That's misleading. They should make in unique and be done with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do it.

Let your friend create a game with a level 60 character, join with your level 70(and maybe let your friend(s) join with their level 70 characters) and just kill all the ubers.

Just don't forget these 2 things:

- Even at Torment 6, you will only have 50% chance of getting an organ
- You can only craft a level 60(iLvl 63) *Hellfire Ring*, which is not even half as good as a decent rare level 70 ring

And as you said, getting a level 60 ring with a level 70 character should not be tough at all(especially when you compare dps/toughness people had at level 60 and now, at level 70)

Comment: old level 60 hellfire rings are a lot better at lower levels than the new ones though.  The old one has a fixed proc for damage where the new one procs based on your weapon damage, so the old one does higher damage when the characters are at low levels.